# Benefit of creating a model plugin when a world plugin exists

Tags: gazebo-plugin

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Is there a benefit to using a model plugin to change the state of a model, if a world plugin that can do that already exists? Or let's say I have 10 models that I want to manipulate at the same time? Or more general, benefit of using "lower level" plugins, when "higher level" ones exist.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/16887/benefit-of-creating-a-model-plugin-when-a-world-plugin-exists/) by [hamzamerzic](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3232/hamzamerzic/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 40 on 2017-07-29

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Whatever you do in a model plugin, you should also be able to do in a world plugin.

Sometimes using a model plugin is more convenient, e.g. when new models are inserted, the model plugin will run automatically, whereas in a world plugin you will have to monitor newly inserted models and verify that's it's the model that you want.

---

Originally posted by [iche033](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/58/iche033/) with karma: 1018 on 2017-08-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0